# Sharepoint 2007 Jsonp Web Services

Tags: 2007, json

Is there a way to get list items from a sharepoint 2007 site via JSONP? I am trying to do a cross domain call from a 2010 instance of sharepoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to stand up a DVWP to emit JSON data which you could then get via AJAX. I've used the following article to do such things locally, and it's worked well. But natively, there are no json endpoint in 2007 so you'd need to spin up your own custom web service to do it, or try the below method.

http://www.metaengine.com/2012/12/Returning-JSON-from-the-SharePoint-DVWP-aka-poor-mans-GetSiteData